# Bubble sort singly linked list in C with pointers

Tags: c, list, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

I am trying to bubble-sort a singly linked list using pointer manipulation in C. I've looked at some other implementations of bubble-sort on the website, but I feel like the logic of my code here should make sense. Even so, still entering into an infinite loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
int counter;
struct node* current = head;
struct node* previous = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node* next = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

for (counter = 0; counter < num_nodes; counter++){
    current = head;
    next = current->m_next;

    while(next != NULL){
        int compare = strcmp(current->m_last_name, next->m_last_name);
        if (compare > 0){
            if (current == head){
                head = next;
            }
            previous->m_next = next;
            current->m_next = next->m_next;
            next->m_next = current; 

            previous = next;
            next = current->m_next;
        }
        else {
            previous = current;
            current = current->m_next;
            next = current->m_next;
        }
    }
}
printf("Loop completely done\n");
```

}

Comment: isn't this a doubly linked list? having next and previous pointers per node...

Comment: calloc() instead of malloc() would be nice so we know pointers started out null. Have to guess your decl of node (singly linked I guess?)

Comment: Meh. Too much code missing, and not even comments to indicate what code you've deleted (well, unless this *is* all the code, in which case, yikes). E.g., how was previous really initialized. Etc.

Comment: Find a list that goes into an infinite loop.  Write down on a piece of paper **every statement that you believe should be executed in order**.  Now walk through your algorithm in the debugger. The moment that a statement is executed that isn't on your list, **that's where the bug is**.

Comment: Your `malloc`s seem to trigger memory leaks. You write `next=malloc()` and four lines later, you write `next=...`. The memory pointed by `next` after malloc is lost ! Bubble sort is possible without using `malloc`. Just carefully modify your pointers...

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses! To francis, I'm new to C so I'm unfamiliar with when I should be using malloc. Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues here. First, why do you allocate memory for the `next` and `previous` node pointers? You are sorting, there are no new nodes involved, you are just shuffling the links between the existing nodes around. What's more, you re-assign the pointers that you have `malloc`ed memory for, e.g.:

```
previous = current;
```

This means, that the value of `previous` and thereby the allocated memory ist lost.

Next, your head pointer will very likely not be the same after sorting. The calling function needs to know about this change. Therefore, you should pass a pointer to a node pointer to your sorting function. (I believe your function to add ndes to a list does that, too.)

The same is true for your `previous` pointer. If this is a node pointer, it is just that: Another pointer pointing to the same node. When you update it, you update a pointer that is external to your list structure. Therefore, `previous` should also be a pointer to node pointer. This pointer is the same as the pointer to the head node pointer at first and then points to the `next` pointers of previous nodes when walking through the list. If you update the pointer pointed to by `prev` you therefore update pointers in your list structure, and that's what you want.

Also, the explicit use of `num_nodes` in your code is very un-list-like. You should use the list structure itself to write the algorithm.

The endless loop is caused by `current` not being updated properly after swapping. Given the misconception of the `malloc`ed pointer I haven't looked much into that.

Here's an implementation that works:

```
void list_bubble_sort(struct node **head) 
{
    int done = 0;         // True if no swaps were made in a pass

    // Don't try to sort empty or single-node lists
    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->m_next == NULL) return;

    while (!done) {
        struct node **pv = head;            // "source" of the pointer to the
                                            // current node in the list struct
        struct node *nd = *head;            // local iterator pointer
        struct node *nx = (*head)->m_next;  // local next pointer

        done = 1;

        while (nx) {
            int cmp = strcmp(nd->m_last_name, nx->m_last_name);

            if (cmp > 0) {
                nd->m_next = nx->m_next;
                nx->m_next = nd;
                *pv = nx;

                done = 0;
            }
            pv = &nd->m_next;
            nd = nx;
            nx = nx->m_next;
        }
    }
}
```

Note how `pv` always contains the source of the internal pointer pointing to `nd` and how pointing to the head node via `*head` is no special case.

The algorithm passes the list from head to tail repeatedly until no changes need to be made. That's a bit crude, but it's bubble sort after all.

**Edit** In another answer, aehrwyn explains why you get an infinite loop. His fix works, but has the flaw of unnecessarily allocating memory and never really using, let alone freeing it. Applying aehrwyn's findings, your code should look like this:

```
struct node *bubble (struct node *head)
{
    int num_nodes = count(head);
    int counter;

    for (counter = 0; counter < num_nodes; counter++) {
        struct node* current = head;
        struct node* next = current->m_next;
        struct node* previous = NULL;

        while(next != NULL) {
            int compare = strcmp(current->m_last_name, next->m_last_name);
            if (compare > 0) {
                if (current == head){
                    head = next;
                } else {
                    previous->m_next = next;
                }
                current->m_next = next->m_next;
                next->m_next = current; 

                previous = next;
                next = current->m_next;
            }
            else {
                previous = current;
                current = current->m_next;
                next = current->m_next;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Loop completely done\n");
    return head;
}
```

Things to note:

- There's no need to malloc anything. The pointers `next` and `previous` are just "working pointers" without proper data; they point to existing nodes.
- I've moved the definition of the working pointers inside the outer loop. This reflects their scope and makes errors such as forgetting to restet them easier to spot, in my opinion.
- You assign `previous->m_next`. I reckon that you were afraid to dereference a `NULL` pointer and therefore allocated a dummy node. Instead, you should have checked for `NULL` before dereferencing. In your code the condition `previous != NULL` is equivalent to `current == head`, so assigning to `previous->m_next` can happen in an `else` clause. Indeed, the if/else reflects the two base cases: Head node and following nodes.
- In my (slighly rantish) explanation above, I've said that you should use pointer to pointers to node, but that's because I thought your code came from a separate function. But it's probably a part of `main`, so using a simple `struct node *` is okay. Note that this works also for separate functions when you return the new head node. You the have to call your function with:

  ```
  head = bubble(head);
  ```

  which in my opinion is error prone, because it's legal to ignore the return value. I prefer the double-pointer approach explained above. (Side note: I see a lot of code here on SO that is one long `main` function. Learn to split your code into small, self-contained functions that you can re-use. It might seem tedious at first, but in the long run this coding style pays dividends.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough response! :) New to C so this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your code is correct, besides the unnecessary mallocing that others have mentioned.

You're entering an infinite loop only because you're not resetting "previous" when you go into the next for loop iteration. So, when you set:

previous->next = next;

previous could be the second to last item in the list, which you set in the while loop in the last for loop iteration. For a quick hacked fix to see that this is the problem, replace your 3rd line with:

```
struct node* previousDummy = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node* previous;
```

and add this right before your while loop:

```
previous = previousDummy;
```

Comment: Good solution, but why do you join in on the unnecessary mallocing? `next` doesn't need any mallocing, it is overwritten immediately. Neither does `previous`. If you want to avoid dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, do so conditionally. So the real fix is to initialise `previous` to `NULL` and only set `previous->m_next` if is is non-null. (This can be an `else` clause to `(current == head)`.

Comment: Yep you're right about your real fix, but as I mentioned, I was just offering a "quick" fix to show where his logic error was, since that was what he was asking about. There are definitely more ways the code can improve...